# Control multiple videos with one control ngx-plyr

Tags: javascript, angular, plyr

I want to control multiple videos with one custom control, i've created minimal repo here https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-plyr-cxla4q?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html i've tried using `querySelectorAll` then listen to an event but not working. did anyone know how to do it?

EDIT

I have found the solutions, here's what i got

i change plyr tag to

```
<video controls crossorigin playsinline
  data-poster="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-HD.jpg" class="js-player">
  <!-- Video files -->
  <source src="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-576p.mp4" type="video/mp4"
    size="576" />
  <source src="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-720p.mp4" type="video/mp4"
    size="720" />
  <source src="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-1080p.mp4" type="video/mp4"
    size="1080" />
</video>
```

then i initiate the player using this code

```
this.listPlayer = Plyr.setup('.js-player', { controls });
```

and then in play function i have this

```
  play(): void {
    this.listPlayer.map(
      e => {
        e.play();
        e.config.muted = true;
        e.config.volume = 0;
      }
    )
  }
```

which solution is the best practices if u compare @yogen darji solution to mine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple mistakes,

1. Use `ViewChildren` to query all your `PlyrComponent`

   `@ViewChildren(PlyrComponent) plyr: QueryList<PlyrComponent>;`
2. Loop through list of components and play each

   `this.plyr.toArray().forEach(plyr => plyr.player.play());`

Sample code with HTML and TS

```
<plyr class="player"  plyrTitle="Video 1" [plyrSources]="videoSources"
 (plyrInit)="player = $event" (plyrPlay)="played($event)"></plyr>
<plyr class="player" appMakered plyrTitle="Video 2" [plyrSources]="videoSources2"
  (plyrInit)="player = $event" (plyrPlay)="played($event)"></plyr>

@ViewChildren(PlyrComponent) plyr: QueryList<PlyrComponent>;
play(): void {
    this.plyr.toArray().forEach(plyr => plyr.player.play());
    console.log(this.elements);        
}

stop(): void {
    this.plyr.toArray().forEach(plyr => plyr.player.stop());        
}
```

Check this updated [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-plyr-pvjqzi?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: wow great! i have another question, i actually trying to find other method, i updated my question, which solutions is best practices

Comment: after i tried ur solution,i think it is better,since i can add inputs whiich i can't do with video tag

Comment: @naovalluthfi I will say, you solution is `pure javascript` based and if you want to use `Angular` you can use above solution